# Can Apple's App Store be considered as a package manager?

Tags: app-store, package-managers

I am trying to understand what a package manager is exactly. According to Wikipedia:

> A package manager or package-management system is a collection of software tools that automates the process of installing, upgrading, configuring, and removing computer programs for a computer's operating system in a consistent manner.

So breaking this definition into it's bits I think the App Store is exactly what a package manager is defined to be be.